# CSS / HTML - Focus automatically leaves input field for no reason

Tags: html, css, layout, input-field

I've got a form laid out using the css below.  Mostly it works well, but whenever there are two input fields with the `<label>` tags I cannot click to select the second field.
If you click the 1st input field it's fine. If you click into the 2nd input field it automatically jumps focus back to the first one.
However, you can tab between the two successfully.

```
div.largeblock{
    margin:5px 0px 20px 0px;
    background:#d7e5f2;
    border:1px solid #d7e5f2;
}
div.largeblock label{
    display:block;
    margin-bottom:5px;
}
div.largeblock label span{
    display:block;
    float:left;
    margin-right:6px;
    width:130px;
    text-align:right;
}
```

```
<label>
   <span>Postcode</span>
   <input type="text" maxlength="4" name="postcode1" required="required" placeholder="Post" />
   <input type="text" maxlength="3" name="postcode2" required="required" placeholder="Code"/>
</label>
```

I have the same problem where I have a `<select>` & `<input>` within 1 label.  But for the other 20 or so lines with just 1 `<input>` it's fine.

Comment: Can you give us a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)? Please?

Comment: New to this and to JSFiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/64CKm/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you click on a `label`, the behaviour in most browsers is to give focus (or check in the case of a checkbox) to the related input.

You need to move the second `input` tag out of the `label` tag. Probably into it's own.

Comment: thank you Matthew.  So it seems to me that the tutorial I followed suggesting using the <label> tag to lay them out is a bit flawed?If I move the second <input> tag out of the <label> it'll mess up the layout.  Or should I just change <label> to some other <tag>

Comment: @showdev thankyou.  But if the HTML goes into <div class="largeblock"> then it splits the line.  http://jsfiddle.net/64CKm/1/

Comment: You want the labels to be "inline" (or floated). Remove `display:block` from `div.largeblock label`: http://jsfiddle.net/64CKm/2/

Comment: @user2990014 : The concept is that `label`s aren't just normal tags for layout.  The `label` tag automatically focuses the `input` inside of it, which is a problem when you have 2 `input` boxes.  Try making the `input`s `display: inline-block;` to cause the boxes aligned.

Answer (score 2):

A `label` element should refer to a single `input` element, using the `for` attribute that should have the same `value` as the `id` of the `input` element it refers to. Otherwise it won't behave predictably, like in your example where the `label` focuses the first `input`, which doesn't make any sense in your example. If you are grouping form elements you should use the element `fieldset` (which can be styled with css to look like a `label`).

The correct syntax would be:

```
<label for="postcode1">Postcode 1</label>
<input type="text" id="postcode1" maxlength="4" name="postcode1" required="required" placeholder="Post" />
<label for ="postcode2">Postcode 2</label>
<input type="text" id="postcode2" maxlength="3" name="postcode2" required="required" placeholder="Code"/>
```

Or if you want to use `fieldset`:

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Postcode</legend>
    <input type="text" maxlength="4" name="postcode1" required="required" placeholder="Post" />
    <input type="text" maxlength="3" name="postcode2" required="required" placeholder="Code"/>
</fieldset>
```